# Standalone Java project vs code to use Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, visual-studio-code

I'm looking to use spark in a standalone VS code java project (ie no maven or gradle).

Is this possible?
I've download library from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html, extracted and copied the contents of Jars folder into my vs code lib folder.

I can see the `spark-core_2.12-3.4.1.jar` along with all the other jars in my referenced libraries.
However if I use `import static spark.Spark.*;` VS code gives the error import spark cannot be resolved.

I imagine I'm missing something very simple but I'm not getting anywhere, everyone seems to be using Maven.

Comment: There's a good reason to use a dependency manager like Maven: Spark is not a single JAR. It's a bunch of JARs because you'll need Spark and all its own dependencies. This does not explain your current error but I'd be challenging your desire of not using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Java, by itself, does not load any libraries from any special location except for the basic library classes from the *rt.jar*. When you run a pure Java application, you need to give it the list of all directories and zip files to be searched for classes, as well as the name of the main class. This set of search locations is called the *classpath*.

Tools like Maven or Gradle simplify selecting and downloading of the libraries, but they also serve another important role: they tell you editor (VC, IntelliJ, Netbeans - whatever) - what should be on the classpath: which classes are available.

If you want to create a Spark application to compile by hand, you will need to:

- Download all the jars that Spark needs. This might mean not only Spark, but also the libraries that Spark itself needs.
- Define your classpath, i.e., a full list of the paths to all the jars downloaded (NOT just the directory storing the jars, but rather the list of the jars within) and your code.
- Find a setting in VC that allows you to set the classpath manually; I can't help you with this, but such a setting exists in IntelliJ, Eclipse, and Netbeans - so I guess it might also exist in VC.

If I had to do it, I would create first a minimal, throwaway Maven project depending on Spark, without any code. In the root of the project I would then run:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This would download both Spark and everything else that is needed into the `target/dependencies` directory. I would copy it out and delete the no-longer-necessary project.

Then I would create a string listing all the jars in the dependency directory joined with `:`. Something like `dependencies/a.jar:dependencies/b.jar:dependencies/c.jar`... etc. This string would be quite long, and it would be exactly what needs to be put into the VC settings (presumably).

I could then also write a Java class and compile it by writing something like:

```
javac -cp dependencies/a.jar:dependencies/b.jar:...:depenendencies/z.jar MyClassToCompile.java
```

And run it by:

```
java -cp dependencies/a.jar:dependencies/b.jar:...:depenendencies/z.jar MyClassToCompile
```

Note that the examples above assume that `MyClassToCompile` is in the default package (otherwise you'd need to append the directories forming the package in the first line and the full qualified name of the class - in the second line).

Answer (score 0):

You should add additional jars via the plus sign to the right of **Referenced Libraries** in the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel.

[image]

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_manage-dependencies-for-unmanaged-folder